# Using delay on Javascript "OpenSel"

Tags: javascript, delay

I'm trying to use delay in certain actions of my code, but I didn't figure how use this function on OpenSel().

Example:

```
function OpenSel(e){1==e?(
    document.getElementById("acin").style.bottom="0",
    document.getElementById("inin").style.bottom="0"
```

I want use delay only on acin, but if I change the css transition, this element will ever been delayed. How can I use delay in only one action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the call in a Javascript `timeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("acin").style.bottom="0"; }, 500);
```

This will run the code after 0.5s

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But if I use this javascript one time, my element will be delayed every time, right? How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking, but why not encapsulate the code in yet another if statement i.e. `if(statement=true){//CodeAbove}else{//OrigionalCode}`

Comment: Well, my idea is use delay in #element1 when I click on button1, but this element is used on other button too (button2), but the action in this button, after the click, need to be direct, with no delay. So, what I need is use delay on action for button1 and don't use on the other button. The OpenSel code can't do that?

Comment: In the event `e`, use it as the `statement`. i.e. `if(e.id()=="button1")`